# OWASP Zaproxy cannot attack URL if its begins with https

Tags: owasp, penetration-testing, zap

I am using the OWASP ZAP Tool (version 2.4.2). The problem is if I choose to attack urls that has https, it always says "Failed to Attack URL". It works fine if the url I entered is not https.

How can I enable it to work with https?

Comment: Have you generated a Dyanmic SSL certificate? ZAP cannot decrypt SSL without a SSL certificate. Also, do you have your browser configured to use ZAP as proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS? The issue could be a number of things, it's hard to know for sure without more detail.

Answer (score 2):

We have a FAQ for that :)

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQquickScanFailed

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)